# How to get upload speed in android?

Tags: java, android, networking, upload, rtmp

I need todo some operations in my android app based on the upload speed. It is an broadcasting app, based on network upload speed I want update the resolution and bitrate. For example if the upload speed is below 0.5 Mb I want to set different bitrate and resolution as 360p. How to measure upload speed?

I tried with Connectivity Manager but it gives only the overall strength. But not the exact speed.

Comment: Would you have any use of an external library, e.g. via Github: https://github.com/topics/speedtest?l=java - if you search for Speedtest with the language Java (or Kotlin), you will find a few options that allow you to do a quick network speed test.

Comment: I tried few of them but it costs lot of data. I want to check speed every 10 seconds

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the following for checking download/upload speed every 5 seconds.

```
import android.net.TrafficStats

object RetrieveData {
    private var totalDownload: Long = 0
    private var totalDownload_n: Long = 0
    private var totalUpload: Long = 0
    private var totalUpload_n: Long = 0
    fun findData(uid: Int): List<Long?> {
        val allData: MutableList<Long?> = ArrayList<Long?>()
        if (totalDownload == 0L) {
            totalDownload = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)
        }
        if (totalUpload == 0L) {
            totalUpload = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)
        }
        val newTotalDownload = TrafficStats.getUidRxBytes(uid)
        val incDownload = newTotalDownload - totalDownload
        val newTotalUpload = TrafficStats.getUidTxBytes(uid)
        val incUpload = newTotalUpload - totalUpload
        totalDownload = newTotalDownload
        totalUpload = newTotalUpload
        allData.add(incDownload)
        allData.add(incUpload)
        return allData
    }
```

and

```
val timer=fixedRateTimer("ss",false,1000,5000){
                getData()
            }
```

and

```
fun getData() {
        val allData = findData(applicationInfo.uid)
        val mDownload = allData[0]
        val mUpload = allData[1]
        val df = DecimalFormat("#.##")
        var downloadSpeedApi=0
        var uploadSpeedApi=0

        var upSpeed: String = if (mUpload!! < 128) {
            mUpload.toInt().toString() + " B/s"
        } else if (mUpload < 1048576) {
            (mUpload.toInt() / 1024).toString() + " KB/s"
        } else {
            df.format(mUpload.toDouble() / 1048576.0).toString() + " MB/s"
        }

        var downSpeed: String = if (mDownload!! < 128) {
            mDownload.toInt().toString() + " B/s"
        } else if (mDownload < 1048576) {
            (mDownload.toInt() / 1024).toString() + " KB/s"
        } else {
            df.format(mDownload.toDouble() / 1048576.0).toString() + " MB/s"
        }

        Log.d("MyTAG", "$downSpeed, $upSpeed")
```

Answer (score 0):

there are 2 ways

1. implement server-side bytes-recived report
   when a large file is uploading to server
   server should calculate recived bytes and response to client every
   seconds so you can calculate exact speed by simple calculation
2. if your server can't report BYTES_RECEIVED you can implement NDK (c++) module  which use HTTP-client ptp transfer
   and you can send bytes from java/kotlin part to ndk and it will calculate WHOLE_BYTES / TRANSFERED_BYTES in last
   second and calculate speed per second

Comment: It gives you only the maximum speed of the network . Not the exact speed